# .val() not setting value

Tags: jquery

I have a text input field called locEmailMsg:

```
<input type="text"
       class="phColor"
       data-placeholder="Your email address"
       maxlength="50"
       style="font-size: 14px; width: 232px;"
       id="locEmailMsg">
```

In my `$(document).ready()` function, I need to do a few things: set the value of the input, set the data-placeholder attribute, and remove the phColor class.

```
$('#locEmailMsg').val(localStorage.email);
$('#locEmailMsg').attr('data-placeholder', localStorage.email);
$('#locEmailMsg').removeClass('phColor');
```

The data-placeholder attribute is being set correctly (watching in Firebug), but the value isn't being set, nor is the class being removed. Why would one part work, but the other parts not work?

This is part of a very large system, but I've stepped through all of the scripts as the page loads, and there's nothing happening after this call that's reversing the value set/class removal.

Comment: theres no possible way you are reusing the same Id is there?

Comment: Try `$('#locEmailMsg').val(localStorage.email).data('placeholder', localStorage.email).removeClass('phColor');`

Comment: Have you tried to set the $('#locEmailMsg') with a hard coded value like $('#locEmailMsg').val("TEST") to make sure the javascript is actually working? If it is, try using localStorage.email.toString()

Comment: I don't see any issue with the above code and It is going to be hard to determine where the problem is with this information. Try adding a console.log or alert above `.val` to check if the value exist and `$('#locEmailMsg').length` to see if the input is selected properly.

Comment: Can you re-create the problem in a jsFiddle? Your code above seems fine.

Comment: Are you sure that your localStorage.email is set? I've tested it with a Jsbin and it works for me

http://jsbin.com/ehesib/1/edit

Comment: @thescientist - no, the id is not being reused anywhere.

Comment: @asawyer - I've tried chaining it; it doesn't make a difference (and shouldn't.) Chained vs. separate lines should work exactly the same.

Comment: @jcalabris - I don't need to - I know the javascript itself is working because the line that sets the data-placeholder attribute works.

Comment: @Vega - I'm not sure what you mean. I know the input is being selected correctly because the line that sets the data-placeholder attribute works. Why would the same exact selector work on that line but not the other two?

Comment: @EmmyS I changed it from `attr(data-` to the proper `.data()` call.

Comment: @AngeloA - yes, localStorage.email is set; as I said, the line that sets data-placeholder works.

Comment: @EmmyS I don't know if you have posted the same exact code here.. It is possible that you may have a typo in there.. so it is better to check.. Also chaining is better because - You select once and use it everywhere against select on every use

Comment: @asawyer - sorry, it was hard to tell there was a difference in the comment. I tried your way, although it doesn't make sense that changing the one part that actually already worked would change the outcome... and it didn't.

Comment: @Vega - yes, it's the exact same code. There's no typo; I pasted it directly from my IDE. And yes, I know chaining is better. As I said to asawyer, I had tried chaining it but it didn't work, so I tried separating them out. It doesn't really help to tell me how to optimize code that isn't working in the first place.

Comment: You really need to post a jsfiddle, in this case. As people have said, your code is correct iff you don't have any duplicate ids, and so people have no other ways to debug.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the value of `localStorage.email`.. or even better try `document.getElementById('locEmailMsg').value = localStorage.email;` oh and btw.. people are leaving a comment here just to suggest a better way to code.. We don't know if you know it or not..

Answer (score 4):

It works here with your code as you have it.

http://jsfiddle.net/bWm2c/1/

However, if an item with the same id occurs again, only the first will be affected.  See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/bWm2c/2/

It doesn't matter if it's an input or not. IDs must be unique.

I put it in a timeout, so you can see the change

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var localStorage = { email: 'foo@bar.com' };

    $('#locEmailMsg')
        .val(localStorage.email)
        .attr('data-placeholder', localStorage.email)
        .removeClass('phColor');
}, 500);
​
```

And here is the failing html (only affects first item)

```
<input type="text"
       class="phColor"
       data-placeholder="Your email address"
       maxlength="50"
       style="font-size: 14px; width: 232px;"
       id="locEmailMsg"
       value="novalue" />

<div id="locEmailMsg">dupid</div>

<input type="text"
       class="phColor"
       data-placeholder="Your email address"
       maxlength="50"
       style="font-size: 14px; width: 232px;"
       id="locEmailMsg"
       value="novalue" />
​
```

This is the only way I can see your code not working.

**EDIT**

Run this on your page to make sure you don't have duplicate ids

http://jsfiddle.net/bWm2c/4/

```
$('[id]').each(function(){
  var ids = $('[id="'+this.id+'"]');
  if(ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this)
    alert('Multiple IDs #'+this.id);
});
​
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try this. I'm aware that IDs must be unique, and my id IS unique. It's not being used anywhere else. And it still doesn't work.

Comment: See my edit, run that code on your page to ensure you don't have duplicate ids.

Comment: @EmmyS, any further progress?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine and It should work fine.. If it doesn't work then there must be some other issue that might be bugging that line..

I would try following to check where it is failing,

1. `console.log` or `alert` the value of `localStorage.email` to see if the value is proper.
2. Try `document.getElementById('locEmailMsg').value = localStorage.email;` to make sure it is not jQuery issue.

Comment: point 2 confirmed it is a jquery issue. Helpful! But strangely enough it is not JQuery. It was the browser cache. When I cleared the history the jquery selector started working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Somehow $('#inputID').val('New Value') was not working however document.getElementById('inputID').value = 'New Value' worked.